# Asp.Net MVC Default Route

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, logging, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have my default route defined like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

However if the user is logged in when they visit the site (This can happen if they ticked the remember me button last time the logged in) I want them to take a different default route and go straight to the logged in page.

Is this possible in global.asax or will I need to put some logic in my home controller to redirect if logged in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best to put this in the home controller.  A check if authenticated and return the appropriate view.

Answer (score 2):

> I want them to take a different default route

[Routing in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/Learn/mvc/tutorial-05-cs.aspx) is about **routing URLs to action methods on controllers**, *not* about routing users to places in your web site depending on the current circumstances. (Think of routing as a static thing, whereas the rest (authorization, redirection, etc) is only applicable to the current session.)

It is possible to u[se Routing Constraints](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-24-cs.aspx) to achieve what you want, but I don't think that's what you want.