# How do I know which controller this page is hitting?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Pretty new to MVC I have a page on an open source application I have downloaded that is at the url...

http://localhost:51930/admin/login?databaseIssue=true

Obviously Im trying to find which controller and view this maps to in the application. How do I work this out? What should I search for and where to look?

Also how do I work out which actions process this view?

Answer (score 2):

This should help you out. This tool is awesome!

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This [guide](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) should get you started. Basically you work with a collection of routes and their arguments, in the global.asax.cs file. The guide there also has a section on custom routes.

Answer (score 0):

By the defaulting routing rules, it's `{controller}/{action}/`

Which would make the controller in http://localhost:51930/admin/login?databaseIssue=true `admin` and the action `Login`.

Answer (score 0):

By convention, MVC routes are generated in form

```
{app_base}/{controller}/{action}
```

Check out [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558902/asp-net-mvc-default-route) for more information.
So in your case, you'll want to look for an `admin.cs` class in your `Controllers` folder.

Answer (score 0):

global.asax is where the route mapping is defined.

You'll see/set something like:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

so by default, your example maps to admin = {controller} and login = {action} and login action method would take the databaseissue=true bit as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

All these answers are good, except in the case where someone may have created a custom route to the specific url in question. By default, they are all correct, but if a custom route was setup, it could be going to the StackController and referencing the Overflow action.

Like Jamie R Rytlweski suggested above, reference RouteDebugger in your project, add the hook in your global.asax and try going to that page, it will show you a listing of all the routes defined in your application and then show you which routes the current page matches